# Is there a "Lebesgue Sum"?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I noticed that the convergence of the series 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + ... is dependent on how you formalize it. If you write $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ and choose $a_n = (-1)^n$, it diverges because the partial sums flip flop between 1 and 0. However, if you choose $a_n = (1-1)$, it clearly converges to 0. But if you wrote both out in "...-notation", then they would look basically identical and the only way to discern them is to remember that the associative propery doesnt always hold for infinite sums so the brackets make a difference (which feels unintuitive to me).

I have heard that there are other summation methods that assign a value to the case $a_n = (-1)^n$. Im not familiar with those. However, it reminded me of the difference between riemann and lebesgue integrals. The riemann integral sums up the terms as it goes, while the lebesgue integral groups all identical terms and multiplies onto them a weight based on their respective measure.

If we apply that same thought here, it feels like we should be able to do a "lebesgue sum". We only have 2 possible terms (1 and 0) analogous to how simple functions only take finitely many values. And exactly "half" the terms are 1 and exactly "half" are 0, so both get a measure of 1/2. So the "lebesgue sum" should be

$1 \cdot 1/2 + 0 \cdot 1/2 = 1/2$

Im aware that the usual lebesgue measure would give these a weight of 0 as $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, and the counting measure a value of infinity as there are infinitely many even and odd numbers. So I guess my second question is that if this summation method is a real thing, what measure is suitable for it? It reminds me heavily of probability measures but now that I think about it, I dont think we ever constructed one on $\mathbb{N}$ and just took it for granted. I only have knowledge of measure theory from analysis 3 and havent taken a dedicated course on it so I wouldnt know

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4688800). You can define summation of series as a Lebesgue integral over the measure space $(\Bbb N,\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N),\nu)$ where $\nu$ is the cardinality / counting measure. But this gives you a slightly different theory as it excludes evaluations such as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}/n=\ln2$

Comment: You should check out the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) as it relates to the first part of your post

Comment: Oh, and you can get a probability measure on $\Bbb N$ just from any $\Bbb N$-valued random variable, for example a Binomial or Poisson distribution (including zero)

Comment: You could also write it as $$1+((-1)+1)+((-1)+1)+\cdots,$$ which obviously converges to $1.$ You see the problem with group the terms.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have already identified the fundamental problem with your approach: there is not really any suitable measure to apply to $\mathbb N$ in order to "Lebesgue-sum" your series.

In your example, you assign weight $1/2$ to the odd numbers and weight $1/2$ to the even numbers, implying that the total weight of $\mathbb N$ is $1$.
Given that statement, you have two choices: either you assign some individual elements of $\mathbb N$ different measures than others, or any individual element of $\mathbb N$ is unmeasurable, because if all elements have measure $\varepsilon>0$ then the measure of $\mathbb N$ is infinite, but if all elements have measure $0$ then the measure of $\mathbb N$ is zero.

This is related to the fact that there is no uniform probability distribution for a discrete random variable that takes all values in $\mathbb N$.

But in any case, I don't think we want to assign weight $1/2$ to the odd numbers and weight $1/2$ to the even numbers, because then we get results like the following.
Consider the infinite series

$$ 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + \cdots. $$

Assigning $a_n$ to $1$ if $n$ is odd and $2$ if $n$ is even, the sum of the entire series is

$$ \frac12 \cdot 1 + \frac12 \cdot 2 = \frac32. $$

In other words, you're not adding up a sum, you're taking some kind of average.

You should also consider how you would find the sum of a series like
$$ 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \cdots. $$
Does the sum not exist (because there is only one term of each value, and each individual element of $\mathbb N$ is unmeasurable),
or do you assign a measure to each element of $\mathbb N$,
so that some of the terms of the series are weighted heavier than others?

If you choose a measure that weights elements of $\mathbb N$ unequally so that the total weight of $\mathbb N$ is $1$, then I think what you would be doing is not summing a series but summing the termwise product of two series, one of which has sum $1.$
The measure that corresponds to the usual definition of the sum of a series is the measure that assigns measure $1$ to every element of $\mathbb N$. With that measure, the  odd terms in $1-1+1-1\pm\cdots$ contribute $\infty$ to the sum and the even terms contribute $-\infty$, and this gives the total $\infty-\infty$.

I would say that $\infty-\infty$ is best regarded as undefined.
If you think $\infty-\infty=0$ then you are saying that
$$999-1+999-1+999-1\pm\cdots = 0,$$
which seems to me a worse result than leaving $1-1+1-1\pm\cdots$ undefined.